# How to show 'Table' instead of 'image' when I have a table in the form of image?

Tags: tables, graphics

I don't know if the question has been asked or not.

I have a table in the form of image and I want to put instead of "Figure 1", I want to put instead "Table 1",

so on my way to show this, I turned to use the following form,

```
\newtheorem{table} {Table}
```

then use it for example,

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{table}
\includegraphics {image1.png}
\end{table}
\end{figure}
```

but this makes the table far away from the image, I just want it at the same place as image, so I hope find here a solution for this problem.

Comment: You can put tabulars in a figure, and graphics in a table.  The only difference between the two is how they affect \caption.  In short, lose the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following code should work for you:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{...}
\includegraphics{image1.png}
\end{table}
```

LaTeX doesn't care whether the tabular material is inserted via a `tabular` environment or by loading an image file.